# rawurlencode not rendering correctly in anchor tag?

Tags: ee2, templates, php

**EE Version. 2.7.3**

I am running rawurlencode on a field in a channel called description to encode it to pass on correctly to twitters sharing url string inside my template.

**Example input:** Check Out Company Names Latest Post!

so the result should be

```
 Check%20Out%20Company%20Names%20Latest%20Post!
```

When I echo it outside of the anchor tag it renders correctly with the proper encoding, but as soon as I echo out the variable inside the anchor tag, the %20 encoding is not rendered and regular spaces are in the URL again.

**PHP**

```
<?php   
    $description =  rawurlencode('{description}');
?>
```

**Output:**

```
 <a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=<?php echo $description; ?> {site_url}" class="popup">
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to [enable PHP in your template.](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/php.html)

Alternatively, you could use a plugin for the URL encoding. For example [URL Encode](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/url-encode) or [CE String.](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ce-string)

It's generally considered not the best practice to enable PHP in templates when an existing plugin or a custom-built plugin allows you to avoid it. Some rationale for that is in this Stack Overflow post, [Is there ever a good reason to use PHP inside ExpressionEngine templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13096532/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-use-php-inside-expressionengine-templates)